# Sublime Text 3 - how to force SumatraPDF in foreground?

Tags: pdf, latex, sublimetext3, pdflatex

When using `Sublime Text 3` (Win7, 64-bit machine) with `LaTeXTools` & `SumatraPDF`, the result of compilation is shown in `SumatraPDF`. At the moment, `SumatraPDF` just pops up shortly into foreground and disappears into background after short popup. Thus, one has to manually bring back `SumatraPDF` into foreground what is lacking of practicability.

Is it possible to force `Sublime Text 3` to keep `SumatraPDF` in foreground after compilation?

Comment: LaTeXTools has the settings `keep_focus`, which retakes the focus from Sumatra. Just open the LaTeXTools settings and set `keep_focus` to false.

Comment: Great, this worked fine! Feel free to write an answer so I can honor you.

Answer (score 1):

LaTeXTools has added the option to retake the focus for Windows in Version `v3.6.0`. To disable this option just open the LaTeXTools settings and change the setting for `keep_focus` to `false`. If you want to toggle the settings temporary just press `ctrl+l`, `t`, `f` as described in the [README](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools#toggling-window-focus-following-a-build).